# Arduino - How to convert double to HEX format

Tags: arduino

I have an arudino code where I get some temperature reading:

```
double c1 = device.readCelsius();
Serial.println(c1);
```

The output is for example: 26.23

What I need is to get this converted to 2623 and then to HEX value so I get: 0x0A3F

Any clue?

Comment: Even a float is 32 bits.  `0x0A3F' is 16 bits.  What is the relationship of that value to 2623?

Comment: Right now I get a double with decimal so I need to get instead of 26.23 2623 and then convert to HEX.

Comment: First you should determine the size of "double" on your specific arduino part.  Many arduinos use smaller types than one might expect.  I don't know what part you're using so cannot help with that.  Then create a union between uint8_t and that type to get bytes.

Comment: `Serial.println(c1*100, HEX);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess your float values always get numbers up to two decimal. So, you can just multiply the value which you read from sensor with a 100.

```
decimalValue = 100 * c1
```

And then you can use this small code for converting the decimal value to HEX.
Thanks to [GeeksforGeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/)

You can find the full tutorial [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/program-decimal-hexadecimal-conversion/)

```
// C++ program to convert a decimal
// number to hexadecimal number
 
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
 
// function to convert decimal to hexadecimal
void decToHexa(int n)
{
    // char array to store hexadecimal number
    char hexaDeciNum[100];
 
    // counter for hexadecimal number array
    int i = 0;
    while (n != 0) {
        // temporary variable to store remainder
        int temp = 0;
 
        // storing remainder in temp variable.
        temp = n % 16;
 
        // check if temp < 10
        if (temp < 10) {
            hexaDeciNum[i] = temp + 48;
            i++;
        }
        else {
            hexaDeciNum[i] = temp + 55;
            i++;
        }
 
        n = n / 16;
    }
 
    // printing hexadecimal number array in reverse order
    for (int j = i - 1; j >= 0; j--)
        cout << hexaDeciNum[j];
}
 
// Driver program to test above function
int main()
{
    int n = 2545;
 
    decToHexa(n);
 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If the whole purpose of `decToHexa()` is to print the hexadecimal of a number to screen, you can do that with `Serial.println(n, HEX);`.

Comment: Or `std::cout << std::hex << n;` for C++.